how do get my code to match? i feel close but im not sure
def stick_game():
    num_sticks = 11
    player = 1
    playing = True

    print("***** WELCOME TO NIM! *****")
    print("Each player will take turns removing")
    print("1, 2, or 3 sticks from the initial 11.")
    print("The player who removes the last stick wins!")
    while playing:
        print(f"\nPlayer {player}, it's your turn!")
        print(f"Here are the sticks remaining: {'|' * num_sticks}")

        move = int(input("How many would you like to remove?"))

        while move < 1 or move > 3 or move > num_sticks:
            if move > num_sticks:
                print("Can not take more sticks than remain. Try again:")
            else:
                print("Invalid move. Try again:")
            move = int(input("Invalid move. Try again: "))


        num_sticks -= move

        if num_sticks == 0:
            print(f"Congratulations Player {player}, you win!")
            playing = False

        player = 2 if player == 1 else 1


stick_game()

 your text
i have to enter 4,0,3,3,3,3,2 i cant use break or while true, i guess its bad practice. this is my first term in python so if its obvious, just know im a scrub
this is the error i get

hint: does anything change in that inner while loop that might cause it to end?

This loop is the problem:
while move < 1 or move > 3 or move > num_sticks:
    if move > num_sticks:
        print("Can not take more sticks than remain. Try again:")
    else:
        print(" Invalid move. Try again:")

You are not assigning a new value to move in the loop, so it keeps its bad value forever.
You need to put another input statement inside the loop.

This is why I generally recommend using while True: and putting the input statement only in the loop. That way you don't have to duplicate it.

we cant use while true: because its bad practice i guess
